# CUDA. torch.cuda.is_available() returns True but my code returns No CUDA GPUs are available

Tags: python, windows, deep-learning, pytorch

When I run the code I get an error

```
  File "C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 247, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available
```

But when I use `torch.cuda.is_available()` I get `True`

[image]

I have last GPU driver v532.03, torch 2.0.1+cu118, Windows 11

I tried to reinstall torch (cu117, cu118), install cuda toolkit from nvidia website, install last gpu driver

Comment: you are sure that you are running you script with same version of the python ?

Comment: @amirhm yes, python3.9